# Solving Piecewise Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, physics, conditional, simulation

I am trying to simulate something using differential equations. However, the equations are piecewise.
Here is my code:

```
z[t_] = y[t] - l Cos[φ[t]];
n[t_] = k Abs[z[t]] - k2 z'[t];
k = 50000000;
k2 = 37;
g = 9.81;
μ = 0.3;
i = 10^-5;
l = 0.01;
m = 0.35;
a = NDSolve[
  If[μ >= (m x''[t])/n[t], (*Condition*)
(*First set of differential equation*)  
{m y''[t] == n[t] - m g,
    φ''[t] == (
     n[t] l Sin[φ[t]] + m x''[t] Cos[φ[t]])/i,
    x''[t] == 
     l (φ''[t] Cos[φ[t]] - φ'[
          t]^2 Sin[φ[t]])},
(*second set of differential equation*) 
   {φ''[t] == (
     n[t] l Sin[φ[t]] + m x''[t] Cos[φ[t]])/i,
    m y''[t] == n[t] - m g,
    m x''[t] == μ n[t]}],
  
  {y[0] == 0.01, 
   y'[0] == -3, φ[0] == 0.01, φ'[0] == 0, 
   x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0},
  {y[t], φ[t], x[t]}, {t, 0, 0.0009}]
```

I am trying to do a numerical simulation:

> 1. When the If condition is satisfied, I would like Mathematica to solve the first set of differential equations.
> 2. When the If conditions is no longer satisfied, I would like Mathematica to continue the simulation with the second set of differential equations.
> 3. When the If condition is satisfied again, it will continue the simulation with the first set of differential equations again. The code will stop running when n[t] becomes 0 (which happens to be the initial conditions as well) .
> 4. Last but not least, I want to plot the graphs of the functions.

I have checked through the two sets of differential equations individually using `NDSolve` and they are all solvable.

I am relatively new to Mathematica and still learning. It would be great if anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: `WhenEvent` maybe one approach.

Comment: Thanks, I will read up more on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks your question. I am also the first time use `WhenEvent` and `If` in ODE,so I am not sure whether it is right or not.

At the beginning,I consider `WhenEvent`,however I cann't find the way. I only get the time `t` when the event  `μ*n[t] >= m x''[t]`  occure. I using the code `WhenEvent[μ*n[t] >= m x''[t] // Evaluate, Print[t]]`

```
z[t_] = y[t] - l Cos[φ[t]];
n[t_] = k Abs[z[t]] - k2 z'[t];
k = 50000000;
k2 = 37;
g = 9.81;
μ = 0.3;
i = 10^-5;
l = 0.01;
m = 0.35;
a = NDSolveValue[{m y''[t] == 
    n[t] - m g, φ''[
     t] == (n[t] l Sin[φ[t]] + 
       m x''[t] Cos[φ[t]])/i, 
   x''[t] == l (φ''[t] Cos[φ[t]] - φ'[t]^2 Sin[φ[t]]), 
y[0] == 0.01, y'[0] == -3, φ[0] == 0.01, φ'[0] == 0, 
   x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[μ*n[t] >= m x''[t] // Evaluate, Print[t]]}, {y[
    t], φ[t], x[t]}, {t, 0, 0.0009}]

(* 0.000263796 *)
```

Then I back to `If` and change the equation `m*x''[t]==μ n[t]` to `x''[t]==μ n[t]/m`,as below. The main settings is

```
  x''[t] == 
    If[(μ*n[t] >= m x''[t]) // Evaluate, (μ n[t]/m) //Evaluate, 
     l (φ''[t] Cos[φ[t]] - φ'[t]^2 Sin[φ[t]])]
```

```
z[t_] := y[t] - l Cos[φ[t]];
n[t_] := k Abs[z[t]] - k2 z'[t];
k = 50000000;
k2 = 37;
g = 9.81;
μ = 0.3;
i = 10^-5;
l = 0.01;
m = 0.35;
a = NDSolveValue[{m y''[t] == 
    n[t] - m g, φ''[
     t] == (n[t] l Sin[φ[t]] + 
       m x''[t] Cos[φ[t]])/i, 
   x''[t] == 
    If[(μ*n[t] >= m x''[t]) // Evaluate, (μ n[t]/m) // 
      Evaluate, 
     l (φ''[t] Cos[φ[t]] - φ'[t]^2 Sin[φ[t]])],
 y[0] == 0.01, y'[0] == -3, φ[0] == 0.01, φ'[0] == 0, 
   x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, {y[t], φ[t], x[t]}, {t, 0, 
   0.0009}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
    "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]
Plot[%, {t, 0, 0.0009}]
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your response. However, when I run it on my mathematica, there are some error messages. Also may i know why is it 3Dplot? I would like to have 3 different graphs of the 3 functions. thank you :)

Comment: Also, I would like to know if it is possible to stop the graph when n[t] becomes 0? Thanks

Comment: @bobthelegend I condiser  n[t] becomes 0 later. I think at that time we can use `WhenEvent`

Comment: Okay i will try to do that thanks

Comment: It gives the following error message `NDSolveValue::mxst: Maximum number of 100000 steps reached at the point t == 6.422554762320297`*^-10.`

Comment: @bobthelegend Maybe we can add `WhenEvent[n[t] == 0 // Evaluate, "StopIntegration"]` to stop

Comment: how do you increase the step size ?

Comment: `WorkingPrecision` , `AccuracyGoal` or `PrecisionGoal` is the three variable which I know.

Comment: @bobthelegend Maybe test `AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 35, MaxSteps -> Infinity` etc.

Comment: But for MaxSteps-> Infinity it will crash. Mathematica gives the following error message `NDSolveValue::precw: The precision of the differential equation  is less than WorkingPrecision (35.`).`

Comment: Hi, I think the "if" does not work very well. When I plot the 2 sets of differential equations separately, the graphs are different.

Comment: @bobthelegend  I had ask one of Wolfram developer, The `WhenEvent` can not  change all the first equation to the second equation,so here we had to use `If`, I am not able to find another way, sorry.