# "If" not working when solving piecewise differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, physics, conditional, simulation, event-detection

This is a part 2 to my previous question:

[Solving Piecewise Differential Equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236893/solving-piecewise-differential-equation)

I am embarking on a physics project and this is the simulation that I would like to do. More information is included below.

Basically, like what was included in the previous post, I would like Mathematica to solve the first set of differential equations shown below: $$m x''(t)=n(t)-mg$$ $$x''(t)=\ell(\phi''(t) \cos \phi- \phi'(t)^2 \sin \phi)$$ $$n(t)\ell\sin\phi+mx''(t)\ell\cos\phi=I\phi''(t)$$

where $n(t)=k|z(t)|-k_2 z'(t)$ and $z(t)=y(t)-\ell \cos(\phi(t))$

**when** $\mu \geq \frac{m x'' (t)}{n(t)}$.

**Once the conditions is no longer satisfied**, I would like Mathematica to continue the simulation with the second set of differential equation, **with the solutions of the previous set of differential equation as the new initial conditions**:$$m x''(t)=n(t)-mg$$ $$n(t)\ell\sin\phi+mx''(t)\ell\cos\phi=I\phi''(t)$$ $$mx''(t)=\mu n(t)$$

**The key thing here is that I do not want mathematica to go back to solve the first set of equations when the condition is satisfied again.** It will only solve the second set until `n[t]==0`. This is why `If` is not suitable in this case !

He has used `If` and `WhenEvent` but both methods do not seem to work in this case (Please take a look at the comments of the previous question as well). His code is shown below:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
z[t_] := y[t] - l Cos[\[CurlyPhi][t]];
n[t_] := k Abs[z[t]]^(3/2) - c z'[t];
k = 50000000;
c = 37;
g = 9.81;
\[Mu] = 0.3;
i = 8.92958*10^-6;
l = 0.01;
m = 0.35;
a = NDSolve[{m y''[t] == n[t] - m g,
   \[CurlyPhi]''[
     t] == (n[t] l Sin[\[CurlyPhi][t]] + 
       m x''[t] l Cos[\[CurlyPhi][t]])/i, 
   x''[t] == 
     If[(\[Mu]*n[t] <= m x''[t]) // Evaluate, (\[Mu] n[t]/m) // 
       Evaluate, 
      l (\[CurlyPhi]''[
           t] Cos[\[CurlyPhi][t]] - \[CurlyPhi]'[t]^2 Sin[\[CurlyPhi][
            t]])] // Evaluate, y[0] == 0.01, 
   y'[0] == -3, \[CurlyPhi][0] == 0.1, \[CurlyPhi]'[0] == 50, 
   x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[n[t] <= 0 // Evaluate, "StopIntegration"]}, {y[
    t], \[CurlyPhi][t], x[t]}, {t, 0, 0.02}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
    "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}, AccuracyGoal -> 17, 
  MaxSteps -> 5000000, PrecisionGoal -> 15]

Plot[y[t] /. a, {t, 0, 0.00125}]
Plot[\[CurlyPhi][t] /. a, {t, 0, 0.00125}]
Plot[x[t] /. a, {t, 0, 0.00125}]
```

These are the graphs the code outputs when I only `NDSolve` the first set of differential equation:
[image]
I got the same set of graphs: [image]

These are the graphs the code outputs when I only `NDSolve` the second set of differential equation:
[image]
Your can see that the y axis value is pretty small.

Moreover, when I change the initial conditions to those that will make perfect sense physically (`y[0] == 0.01,  y'[0] == -3, \[CurlyPhi][0] == 0.2, \[CurlyPhi]'[0] == 50, x[0] == 0,  x'[0] == 0`), there will be this error message: `NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.`

Therefore, because of this error message, I am unable to change the initial conditions around and see if the graph plotted is piecewise. (from the current graph I got, it does not seem to be piecewise)

How can I do this simulation in Mathematica?
Please send help. Thank you :)

Comment: Please make your question self-contained by including all the necessary code here. Show how you attempted to use the `If` and `WhenEvent` approaches in this case (with code) and explain exactly how they fail (error? Unexpected result? If the latter, What is the expected result then?)

Comment: @bob the legend: I have a similar issue in a model of ODEs in which there are many singularities. Can you give us your trial `Code`?

Comment: @bob the legend: Maybe `With` is better than `If` statement because you can easily divide the entire problem into two segments with different conditions.

Comment: Hi I have included the trial code. Thank :) @MarcoB

Comment: The results that I got were 3 graphs for the 3 functions respectively. However, when I tried running the two sets of equations separately using `NDSolve` the graphs that I got for the first set of equations are exactly the same as the graphs I got from this code, which is wrong. The code should instead combine the two graphs in some way. Thanks @ MarcoB @Tugrul Temel

Comment: Did you plot `n[t] /. a`?  The title points to it being connected to the problem, but it's not one of the plots you included.

Comment: Hi @Michael E2, I changed my title and included the graphs in the question post. The main reason why I am unable to see whether `If` actually works is because I am unable to change around the initial conditions to see if the graph becomes piecewise visually at some point. The error message I got when I changed the initial conditions around was also included in the post. Thanks